# How to create a ForEach loop in LaTeX algorithms using "algorithmic"?

Tags: algorithms

The question is already in the title. I am using "algorithmic" as package and can not find any reference for "FOREACH" definition. I already know that for "algpseudocode" I could use

```
% define macro foreach
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
```

But I can not find something similar for "algorithmic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the content that is created for `\FORALL` and replace the necessary elements to create a `\FOREACH`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
% Taken from \FORALL within
%   http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.dtx
\newcommand{\algorithmicforeach}{\textbf{for each}}
\newcommand{\FOREACH}[2][default]{%
  \ALC@it\algorithmicforeach\ #2\ \algorithmicdo%
    \ALC@com{#1}\begin{ALC@for}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \FORALL{$i$ such that $0 \leq i \leq 10$}
    \STATE carry out some processing
  \ENDFOR
  \FOREACH{$i$ such that $0 \leq i \leq 10$}
    \STATE carry out some processing
  \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did just realize that there seems to be "FORALL" in algorithmic, so one can do:

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FORALL{$i$ such that $0\leq i\leq 10$}
\STATE carry out some processing
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
```